Can ERC721-C enforce fees in any NFT Marketplace?
I have been reading about ERC721-C standard, to allow enforceable fees, in this link from OpenSea
The document states the following:

This interface is implemented by ERC721SeaDrop, ERC1155SeaDrop, and
the LimitBreak creator contracts, or can be implemented manually in
your own token contracts.

Is this Standard only for OpenSea, or there are other NFT marketplaces that are supporting this standard to make fees enforceable to many marketplaces at the same time?
